# Openfire Custom Database

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am working with Openfire with external MySQL database created with the default `openfire_mysql.sql` from the Openfire server resources folder.

What I am trying to accomplish is to make the attribute persistence work, as described in the Smack API. Attribute stored using `createAccount(String username, String password, Map<String, String> attributes)` and retrieved using `getAttributes`

However it seems that the default external database setup is not up for persisting these attributes, I already tried manually adding the row yet still attributes are not persisted.

Anyone have encountered this requirement before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to do this as well and have looked through some of the openfire sourcecode. I believe the method that persists into the database only handles the fields written in the default openfire_mysql.sql file. You would have to go and modify those new fields into the source code for them to be covered.